# Getting related entries along with entry using the Element API plugin

Tags: relations, elementcriteriamodel, json, plugin-elementapi

I want to list all the related entries to the entry I am displaying using the Element API plugin.

I have a channel called series and another called episodes, the episodes have a relationship with 1 series.

I am pulling in the series ok:

```
'api/series.json' => [
    'elementType' => 'Entry',
    'criteria' => ['section' => 'series'],
    'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
        return [
            'title' => $entry->title,
            'url' => $entry->url,
            'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("api/series/{$entry->id}.json")
        ];
    },
],
```

Then I am pulling in a series:

```
'api/series/<entryId:\d+>.json' => function( $entryId) {
        return [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => [
                'id' => $entryId
            ],
            'first' => true,
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'image' => $entry->seriesHero,
                    'description' => $entry->seriesDescription
                ];
            },
        ];
    },
```

In the endpoint above I want to be able to output an array of the episodes related to this series.
The relationship field in the episode channel is called `series`.

What is the best way to do this?